# jQuery element property

Tags: jquery

is there a way to create/add multiple elements at once? In the following example I would like *span* and *ul* to be both innerHTML properties of li:

```
jQuery('<li/>', {
  html: jQuery('<span/>', {
    text: 'a',
  }), jQuery('<ul/>', {
    text: 'b',
  })
}).appendTo("#t");
```

I would like to do it in one call, without having to pass a string of HTML (which I did before).

Thanks

Comment: `$('#t').append('<li><span></span><ul></ul></li>')` something like this? edit: ah, without a string of HTML. You mind me asking why you don't want to do it this way?

Comment: Jules, Felix's answer is what I wanted, I do not want to pass a string of HTML

Comment: Jules: because for each element, I need to specify a bunch of attributes

Comment: If i'm not mistaking, after passing the html as a string, jquery will interpret the string as elements. So you could still add a bunch of attributes to each element afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
jQuery('<li/>')
   .append(jQuery('<span/>', {text: 'a'})
   .append(jQuery('<ul/>',  {text: 'b'})
   .appendTo("#t");
```